# specific character recognition with machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

Identify not only the type of character but also produce different output based on the different orientation of the same character.
for example, if the 'y' is bold, small, big, loop, no loop etc, it should be able to produce different output based on a different characteristic of the same character.
So, What am I looking at?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting program... good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not here to write the program for you or to recommend reading materials but rather to assist with problems that you have encounter during the coding processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if your question is "Can I build this ?", Then the answer is **yes**.
You could train an SVM model to predict the characters based on it's properties (There may be other models, check them out!). As for the question "Can I use a file from paint ?", If you are ready to spend a lot of time drawing random images of all characters, then yes, you can. Rather than doing that, check for any publicly available character datasets, similar to MNIST. And then train the model using that rather, than building your own dataset on paint.